# JAVA What is the most optimal way to call Object array methode where property is equal to a string?

Tags: java, string, linq

If I have a String table object in java

```
Student [] student = new Student [10];
```

Let's imagine

```
student[0].setName("TOMATO");
student[1].setName("POTATO"); 
student[2].setName("APPLE");
```

How to call a methode from the object but where the attribute name is equal potato?

If we were using Linq this would be something like :

```
for(int i=0 ; i<student.lenght; i++)
sutent[i].myMethode().where(sutent[i].getName().equal("POTATO"));
```

But how to do it in JAVA?

I tried to use **indexOf(String str)** but it seems to give me weird results

Thank you

Comment: One hint: you could sort the array based on the name. Then you can use binary search to avoid a full scan of the array later on.

Comment: You complain about a loop in the accepted answer but show a loop in your LINQ example (which isn't close to right, btw). If you are using Java 8 I believe you should be able to get close to LINQ using forEach and lambda's  - something like `Arrays.stream(student).filter(x -> x.getName().equals("POTATO")).forEach(s -> s.myMethode());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate through your `Student array` to find the particular student object in the array on which you want to call the method.

```
class Student{
    private String name;

    Student(){
        name = ""; // initialization
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    void somemethod(){ // or any other return type and parameters
        ...
    }
}

public class Main{
    Student[] student = new Student[10];
    student[0] = new Student();
    student[1] = new Student();
    ...
    student[0].setName("TOMATO");
    student[1].setName("POTATO"); 
    ...
    for(Student s : student) {
        if(s != null && s.getName.equal("POTATO")) {
            s.somemethod();// call on s
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time , but there is no way to avoid making a loop?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to go through each of the `student item` from array. This occurs in linear time i.e. `O(n)` where `n` is the size of student array.

Answer (score 3):

The typical Java answer would be: you would be looking into using a Map instead of an array.

The map key would be the name of the student, and the map value the corresponding student object.

Now looking up that student becomes an O(1) operation at the cost of more memory.

In other words: if accessing student objects by name is your primary use case, then an array is the wrong data structure.

Comment: `if accessing student objects by name is your primary use case, then an array is the wrong data structure.` Just perfect :)

Comment: Indeed, you are 100% right , but as I'm tutoring a student ,I'm limited and  the array must be used as a data structure . But, as It's been a long time I haven't use arrays I was wondering if there was a way they behave like Map and linked list etc... as you explained . But thank you for pointing it out

Comment: There isn't. You have to use arrays and loops then.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8+:

```
Stream.of(student).filter(s -> s.getName.equals("POTATO"))
    .forEach(s -> /* whatever */);
```